# How to retrieve user's friends going to a Facebook event using api v2.0?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Given that you can only download the friends list of people using the app in v2.0, and not all the attendees of an event will use the app, does this mean we can't show users which friends are going?

Answer (score 1):

I found the absence of an api call that gives you a user's full friend list a little weird myself. I still feel I may be missing something.

Meanwhile this is the workaround I could think of:

You can use `/{event-id}/attending` to find all people attending an event and then use `/{user-a-id}/friends/{user-b-id}` to check if they are friends with a particular user, with this you can create a list of friends of a user who are attending an event.

This might be quite slow though.